# cakephp how to handle errors on saveField

Tags: php, cakephp

Guys i am wondering if there is a way to error handle saveField() in cakePhp. I tried to produce an error manually by setting for example a fake column

```
$saveCss = $this->Menu->saveField('fakeColumn','test');
```

But i get the same result as an existing column. Any ideas how to handle them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got a beforeValidate() or beforeSave() method in the model or app model? Ifso, are they returning true? Failing that, use a debugger.

This will probably give you the info you need

```
 if(!$this->Menu->saveField()){
        debug($this->validationErrors); die();
    }
```

You can use Cake Guide as reference http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html